# QDial making notch values visible

Tags: qt, qdial

I am using `QDial` in my program and have been trying to get the notch values visible in a `QDial`. Does any one have an idea on this.

So far I have figured that I might be able to extend the `QDial` and put lables there for notches can some one assist me by telling me what methods should I use in extending `QDial` For this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately none of QAbstractSlider subclasses display labels by default. You will have to extend base class functionality and draw the labels yourself.Another alternative is to use QWT. http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_dial.html .

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I decided to use extending the bass class option. Will publish the code for anyone whom interested.